# Please delete this account

Tags: discussion

I have already filed 2 deletion requests of this account.

It has not been deleted yet.

What else do I need to do to get this account deleted?

Thanks!

Comment: **Note** – a new deletion process is now in place, as per: [We've drastically simplified the user deletion process!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300185/300411)

Answer (score 3):

There is a 24 hour deletion request queue From the time a staff member takes action that accounts are placed in when you request deletion.

This is to give you the opportunity to change your mind (people do that sometimes), before it takes a lot of effort to recover your account.

I can tell from your profile that the request to delete has gone through. However it is still pending action by SE staff on your request. You should be deleted 24 hours after a staff member processes your request.

This will show up in a timer on your profile when it has been processed.

Comment: Got it, thanks!